# How to automatic change the menu bar into drop down list when on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a desktop and mobile site.and I would like to have the menu bar, when on desktop site, show full menu and when on mobile site show only one button with drop down menu. by any chance anyone know how to make this?is using bootstrap can make it? but how?Please help.

Just like this site..scale your browser and you will see the menu button.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do with bootstrap.

This is copied straight from the bootstrap Docs.

Read the documentation [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar). Most notably the "Responsive Navbar" section.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

         <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
         <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </a>

         <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
         <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

         <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
         <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
             <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Schmalzy, thanks for your reply. But if I dun want to use the ui design by bootstrap, by any chance I can make that too?

Comment: @SoKim You can use the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) page to change the UI if you would like. Or simply override the default bootstrap CSS with your own customized CSS.